# Почему ссылки с множествами не работают так как с другими изменяемыми типами, типа списков или словарей?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
b = a
a.update({3: 'c'})
a[4] = 'd'
print(a)
print(b)
# {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
# {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}

a = [1, 2]
b = a
a.append(3)
a.extend([4, 5])
print(a)
print(b)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a = {1, 2}
b = a
a.add(3)
a.update([4, 5])
print(a)
print(b)
# {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
# {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: попробовал ваш код, всё работает # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Comment: мдэ, теперь у меня тоже работает -___-, спасибо

Comment: Такого не может быть, потому что во всех ваших случаях `b` - это просто ссылка на `a` и поэтому содержимое у них всегда будет одинаково.